# Do give a darn 'bout my so-so reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I'm very happy to be a part of this process.  It is exciting to participate in it and hopefully see it grow into an active site here on SE.

I was looking at the reputation page - on the meta and the main - and, well, wow, I have not a lot of reputation.  I'm not having any sort of rep envy here, but I must not be doing as much as I could to help this site along.

In point of fact, I'm not even sure this should be on the meta site.  Vote the question down, if you think that's appropriate, but can someone tell me what I should be doing to improve the site?

TIA,

Chris

Comment: There are some limits to what we can do in the private beta. In the public beta, we'll be able to promote the questions and drive more traffic, which will drive more voting activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking and answering questions on the main [Genealogy SE](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com) site is the best way to help the site -- and earn reputation :)  Activity on the meta site does not affect reputation.

The highest amount of reputation is gained by the following actions:

> - one of your questions is voted up/useful: +5
> - one of your answers is voted up/useful: +10
> - one of your answers becomes accepted: +15
> - you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site

For the complete list of actions that earn (and deduct) reputation, see [How does "reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) in the StackExchange FAQ.

Comment: Editing is another important way to gain reputation.

Answer (score 4):

I support efgen's answer but wanted to add that you need to do your part and help other people's reputations as well. If you see an answer you like, vote it up. If you see an answer that violates the rules or scope of the site (and not just because you don't like the answer) vote it down. Since you asked this question, if efgen's answer is what you were looking for, then click the check box that the question was answered. Only you, the asker, has that option. If their answer suited your needs - make sure they get the credit they deserve. This is a crowd sourced site and you have to do your part for others as well.

Note if you hover over your name you will see how many votes you cast today, this week, this month. Do your part and get those numbers up. It won't help your reputation but it will help others. If everyone does that, your reputation will grow as others vote your q&a's up. If no one votes, no one's reputation grows. This is a new site so many people are hesitant to vote. Don't hesitate to vote up good questions and good answers.

Comment: I want to add that, while you don't have to leave a comment if you downvote, if you *do* leave a comment. Please be *nice* and explain to the person how they might improve their post. :) We're doing a great job of this, but it doesn't hurt to keep reiterating it!

Comment: Duncan, voting and accepting responses here on meta is definitely appreciated and beneficial, but it actually doesn't affect reputation :)  Only activity on the main Genealogy SE site affects reputation.  I've updated my original answer to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

As with all SE sites, contribute where you can... reputation will follow in due course.